# CodeIgniter json requests gives cannot modify header information when output->set_header is used in controller's constructor

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, http-headers

I have a custom controller extending CI_Controller (codeigniter version 2.1.4) which has the following code

```
class SM_Restricted extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->output->set_header('Last-Modified:'.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').'GMT');
    $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
    $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0',false);
    $this->output->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');

    if (!$this->session->userdata('isLoggedIn')){
        redirect('login','refresh');
    }
}}
```

all the other controllers are extended from this one except the login controller.

All the views are loading fine. But when JSON requests are made to any of the controllers 'Cannot Modify Header Information' Error is written into the log file but the response doesn't have the error.If I remove the set_header() functions from the constructor then JSON requests are working fine no errors are logged.

Why is this happening? How to overcome this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for an AJAX request and load the headers accordingly.

```
if(!$this->input->is_ajax_request())
{
    $this->output->set_header('Last-Modified:'.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').'GMT');
    $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
    $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0',false);
    $this->output->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Craig..Thanks for the solution.Any Idea why this happens?

Comment: Do you have anything in your log files?

Comment: After the fix errors are not coming.All the debug statements are there since I enabled logging of all types. Before the fix the log had 4 error messages each for every JSON request pointing to the line 'echo json_encode($response)'. example error : Severity: Warning  --> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/appname/application/controllers/dashboard.php:66) /var/www/html/appname/system/core/Output.php 391